# Number of unique combinations

Tags: java, algorithm

For example I have a list of letters: 
"a, b, c, a, d, a, a, b"
How can I find a number of combinations which can be made up of this letters? Any length. Combinations like "ab" and "ba", "aab" and "aba" - not unique.

Comment: try something then let us know how you failed

Comment: there's a formula for this. 2^n - 1 where n is the number of element in your set. so if you have a list of letters with 10 entries then 2^n - 1 = 2 ^ 10 - 1 = 1024 - 1 = 1023. This will be the powerset which does not include an empty set. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set

Comment: Heap's algorithm will give you a starting point https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm

Comment: Is it just syntetic task, or it is required for something useful?)

Answer (score 1):

Let's there are C(i) entries of i-th element in the given set.
Then number of possible subsets (not counting empty one) is

```
M = (С[1] + 1)  * (C[2] + 1) * ...* (C[N] + 1) - 1  // product of these values
```

For your example (4 x a, 2 x b, 1 x c, 1 x d)

```
M = (4+1)*(2+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)-1 = 5*3*2*2-1 = 59
```